# Getting frame/origin of UIButtons that are outside of visible view in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

How do I go about getting the correct frame (and more importantly, origin) of a UIButton that is outside of the current visible area of a UIScrollView? It seems like when they are not visible, I get erroneous values (i.e. I layout a subview using the frame values I receive, and when I scroll down to it, it is in the wrong place.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I've answered my own question. If you have outlets and/or references to your buttons, you'll want to re-reference your button/label/custom view frames in the scrollViewDidScroll method. In my case, I was trying to line up a custom view frame with a button frame, so the implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    // Enumerate through each object you're looking to reposition and compare them:
    if(!(CGRectEqualToRect(bsv.frame, btn.frame))) bsv.frame = btn.frame;
```

I hope this will help someone out there.